# How do I start Thinking Sphinx delayed delta rake task from deploy script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, thinking-sphinx

I have Thinking Sphinx setup and working however I am having a problem getting the Delayed Job rake tasks to start during deployment.

I have the following task in deploy.rb which appears to execute, however the delayed jobs are not processed - they stack up until I run rake ts:dd from the server command line:

```
namespace :thinkingsphinx do
  desc 'Start Delayed Job Sphinx delta indexing'
  task :dd do
    run "cd #{current_path} && rake ts:dd RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} &" 
  end
end
```

How can I get the delayed jobs to start running from the deployment script?

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](http://amitsolanki.com/2010/04/running-delayed-delta-daemon-in-background-for-thinking-sphinx/#comment-5802) Florian provided has code by Amit Solanki that works!

Here is what I did to get this to work with Capistrano:

**Install gems**

- [ts-delayed-delta](http://github.com/freelancing-god/ts-delayed-delta/)
- [daemon_generator](http://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator)
- [whenever](http://github.com/javan/whenever)

**Create a file called `script/delayed_delta` with the contents:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'
dir = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..'))

daemon_options = {
  :multiple => false,
  :dir_mode => :normal,
  :dir => File.join(dir, 'tmp', 'pids'),
  :backtrace => true
}
puts 'delayed_delta'

Daemons.run_proc('job_runner', daemon_options) do
  if ARGV.include?('--')
    ARGV.slice! 0..ARGV.index('--')
  else
    ARGV.clear
  end

  Dir.chdir dir
  RAILS_ENV = ARGV.first || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
  require File.join('config', 'environment')

  Delayed::Worker.new(
    :min_priority => ENV['MIN_PRIORITY'],
    :max_priority => ENV['MAX_PRIORITY']
  ).start
end
```

**Configure Capistrano**

Capistrano needs to start **Sphinx** and **job_runner** (with our `script/delayed_delta`).

Add something like this to the `deploy.rb`:

```
deploy.task :restart, :roles => :app do
  run "export RAILS_ENV=production && cd #{deploy_to}/current && /usr/bin/rake ts:rebuild"  
  run "export RAILS_ENV=production && cd #{current_path} && /usr/bin/ruby script/delayed_delta start"
end
```

**Configure `whenever` gem**

In your `config/schedule.rb` add lines to update Sphinx's index and start job_runner if it isn't already running

```
every 30.minutes do
  command "export RAILS_ENV=production && cd /path/to/rails/production && /usr/bin/rake ts:index && /usr/bin/ruby script/delayed_delta start"
end
```

This gets converted to a **crontab** that is run every 30 minutes to update sphinx

**Final Notes and Lessons Learned**

- The `script/delayed_delta` uses the **daemon_generator** gem to start the **job_runner** background worker script. This is equivalent to running `rake thinking_sphinx:delayed_deltas` on the console, but persistent.
- Make sure only one **job_runner** or `rake thinking_sphinx:delayed_deltas` process is running at one time
- Let Capistrano start both Sphinx (rake ts:rebuild) and `script/delayed_delta`. I had problem when I started sphinx and delayed_deltas from different users or different environments

Answer (score 2):

This link will be useful for anybody who need to restart the delayed_delta rake task from deploy script :

http://amitsolanki.com/2010/04/running-delayed-delta-daemon-in-background-for-thinking-sphinx/#comment-5802

Answer (score 1):

I would put your delayed_job task in a separate script and run it from cron or have it started/monitored by your monitoring tool of choice (e.g., `monit`).  Your deploy script can just kill it to make sure it restarts each time (`killall job_runner`).  Here's the script I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
## this script is for making sure and delayed_jobs get run
##   it is used by thinking sphinx
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment'

# you can also put the definition of this in config/environments/*.rb so it's different for test, production and development
JobRunnerPidFile = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/pids/job_runner.pid" 

if File.exists?(JobRunnerPidFile)
  old_pid = File.read(JobRunnerPidFile).to_i
  begin
    if Process.getpgid(old_pid) > 0
      # still running, let's exit silently...
      exit(0)
    end
  rescue
    # looks like nothing is running, so let's carry on
  end
end

File.open(JobRunnerPidFile, "w") {|f| f.write "#{$$}\n" }

Delayed::Worker.new.start
```